# Finding an exponential formula passed upon the start and end points.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

I'd like to create pricing curve that's based upon a reverse exponential function. I know the starting point and ending point, but don't know how to create the curve in between.

For example, say for 100 units we have a price of 50 p/unit, and for 500 we have 25 p/unit. How can I create the range of values in between?

Comment: Have you looked at linear regression?

Comment: Actually that seems to be overkill, and unnecessary see my answer

Answer (score 0):

So our exponential function will be for the form: $P = C_1*C_2^u$

where P = price, u = units, and $C_1, C_2$ are two constants we are attempting to determine.

To solve this consider the two cases you were given:

$$ 50 = C_1*(C_2)^{-100} $$

$$ 25 = C_2*(c_2)^{-500} $$

We now take the $\log_{10} $ of both sides

$$ \log_{10}(50) = \log_{10}(C_1*(C_2)^{-100}) $$

$$ \log_{10}(25) = \log_{10}(C_1*(C_2)^{-500}) $$

This we expand the products using the log product to sum rule:

$$ \log_{10}(50) = \log_{10}(C_1) + \log_{10}((C_2)^{-100}) $$

$$ \log_{10}(25) = \log_{10}(C_1) + \log_{10}((C_2)^{-500}) $$

We now simplify the exponents using the log power to product rule

$$ \log_{10}(50) = \log_{10}(C_1) - 100*\log_{10}((C_2)) $$

$$ \log_{10}(25) = \log_{10}(C_1) - 500*\log_{10}((C_2)) $$

subtract the top equation by the bottom

$$ \log_{10}(50) - \log_{10}(25) =   400*\log_{10}((C_2)) $$

$$ \log_{10}(25) = \log_{10}(C_1) - 500*\log_{10}((C_2)) $$

Therefore:

$$ 10^{\frac{\log_{10}(\frac{50}{25} = 2)}{400}} = C_2$$

Now substitute this value of $C_2$ back into the second equation and solve for $C_1$